# If you can replace a router with just a raspberry pi and some code

Tags: networking, router, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to figure out the bare minimum in order to create a network. Wondering if you need to actually *always* buy a router, or if you can instead connect devices like Raspberry Pis directly with ethernet cords and have one of them with some OS or software that somehow handles its own virtualized routing. Basically I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to network machines (like Raspberry Pis) without a "router" like the ones you typically buy from the store. Instead, you could build a virtual router from an ordinary computer.

Comment: Yes, in theory. However, it will be glacially slow compared to a router, since the router's hardware is optimized for switching and the Pi is not; also, the router's code, is very carefully optimized and tweaked, but yours will not be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Raspberry PI has only one Ethernet interface, but you can add a USB Ethernet dongle, adding a second network interface. You can then configure  as a router.

For the Wi-Fi, some Raspberry Pis have a Wi-Fi chip and can act as Access Points, or you can a USB Wi-Fi dongle and use that as an access point.

My advice would be to purchase a router compatible with openwrt.

Openwrt (https://www.openwrt.org) is a 100% open-source firmware for very common hardware you can purchase on the market.

Comment: *"Raspberry PI has only one network card "* -- The RPi is a SBC (single board computer) or a single card (board).  You're misusing the term *"card"* when you actually mean "interface".  Back in the day of PCs and modular computers, an interface would be implemented on an expansion board, aka a "card".  It's called a "card" because it resembled an index card.